# Google Maps dynamic URL generation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url

I have just the source and destination coordinates and I would like to plot a path between the two. Using the google maps urls that are generated by the maps website I have seen them to search and pin-point a place with names. Since I would like to just pass source and destination coordinates I have no idea how its done.

A sample URL https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Wall+Street,+New+York,+NY,+United+States&daddr=New+York,+NY&hl=en&sll=40.714353,-74.005973&sspn=0.312274,0.441513&geocode=FUUnbQIdPriW-ynxKrREPlrCiTEa7wMmAK6YDw%3BFXFAbQIdK8KW-yk7CD_TpU_CiTFi_nfhBo8LyA&oq=Wall&mra=ls&t=m&z=16

Here you can see the name of the place is passed with just one set of the coordinates. Could someone enlighten me on how I can map that to source and destination coordinates. Hence

A sample URL https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=(SourceCoordinate)&daddr=(destinationCoordinates)&hl=en&TypeOfDirections=Walking

The last point is where I am still stuck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=40,-117&daddr=45,-114&hl=en

Comment: Hi, well also in the directions, could you please tell me if walking directions can be passed in the  query parameter?